# combine json array into one json array by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to merge item and purchases array of json into one by matching their property value.

Here's the source :

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "invoiceId": 1
        },
        {
            "invoiceId": 2
        },
        {
            "invoiceId": 3
        }
    ],
    "purchase": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "date": "12/1/2014"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "date": "12/1/2014"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "date": "12/1/2014"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to produce something like this :

```
{
    "combined": [
        {
            "invoiceId": 1,
            "id": "1",
            "date": "12/1/2014"
        },
        {
            "invoiceId": 2,
            "id": "2",
            "date": "12/1/2014"
        },
        {
            "invoiceId": 3,
            "id": "3",
            "date": "12/1/2014"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I match the item.invoiceId with purchase.id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

**assuming `obj` is your object**

```
var new_obj = {combined:[]};
obj["purchase"].forEach(function(a) {
    obj["item"].forEach(function(b){ 
        if (+b["invoiceId"]===(+a["id"])) {
            a["invoiceId"] = b["invoiceId"] || 0;//WILL MAKE INVOICEID 0 IF IT IS NOT DEFINE. CHANGE 0 TO YOUR NEEDS
            new_obj.combined.push(a);
        }
    });
});
```

### How it works

The first `.forEach()` loops through `obj.purchase`. Then we loop through `obj.item` To check if their is a matching invoiceId *(if you don't need to make sure their is a matching invoiceId, use the **alternate code**)*. Then, we simply add a new value to the `new_obj`

---

The result *(copied from console)* is:

```
{
    "combined":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "date":"12/1/2014",
            "invoiceId":1
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "date":"12/1/2014",
            "invoiceId":2
        },
        {
            "id":"3",
            "date":"12/1/2014",
            "invoiceId":3
        }
    ]
}
```

### Alternative Code

Use this if you don't need to make sure, `invoiceId` is there

```
var new_obj = {combined:[]};

obj["purchase"].forEach(function(a){a["invoiceId"]=a["id"];new_obj.combined.push(a);});
```

Comment: curious to know what is +a["a"] here

Comment: @JamesLemon That just converts it into an Number. It's shorthand for `parseInt`/`parseFloat`

Comment: @JamesLemon Simple fix, add a `+` before the `b`, I updated my answer. Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/ap417mde/1/

Comment: just curious how the casting work. is it just add a `+` in any variable and it will become an integer?

Comment: @JamesLemon  I'm guessing it thinks it's a math equation so it'll convert it.  Also because multiplying  `*1` will convert it. Example `'5'*1`

Comment: thanks for that, in my fiddle example, other property is missing after the merging. How to keep those in place within the loop? The slots object have many other property.

Comment: I see just add them into the a object, hey mate big thanks to u solved my headache!

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving what you want will be

```
var result = {};

var getMatchingPurchase = function(invoiceId) {
    return data.purchase.filter(function(purchase) {
        return invoiceId == purchase.id; 
    })[0];
};

result.combined = data.item.map(function(invoice) {
    var purchase = getMatchingPurchase(invoice.invoiceId);
    return {
        invoiceId: invoice.invoiceId,
        id: purchase.id,
        date: purchase.date
    };
});

console.log(result);
```

It will print like bellow

```
{ combined:
   [ { invoiceId: 1, id: '1', date: '12/1/2014' },
     { invoiceId: 2, id: '2', date: '12/1/2014' },
     { invoiceId: 3, id: '3', date: '12/1/2014' } ] }
```

**Note:-** I'm using **map** and **filter** functions which are not supported in IE8. If you want to use in IE8 you have to use **for loop.**

Comment: says invoice id is my priority, will the id become null and the loop is still going?

Comment: @JamesLemon do you mean if there is not matching purchase for an inovoice ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to support old browsers like IE8 (poor guy...), note that the native `forEach` might not be supported, in this case you can use lodash for cross-browser compatibility:

```
function getCombinedResult(source){
    var combinedList = [];
    _.each(source.item, function(item){
        _.each(source.purchase, function(purchase){
            if (item['invoiceId'].toString() != purchase['id'].toString()) return;
            var combinedItem = _.extend(item, purchase)
            combinedList.push(combinedItem);
        });
    })
    return {"combined": combinedList};
}
```

Comment: `.forEach` is a 1.9 specification. Pretty much every browser nowadays *should* support it, even IE

Comment: you're right, it's fine since IE 9, editted to make it more clear